# How to read .cfg and .weights file in opencv android app

Tags: android, opencv, yolo

I tried using
where I had my files saved in lumber folder in phone

```
`String cfgPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/lumber/yolov3_custom.cfg";
String weightsPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/lumber/yolov3_custom_final.weights";
yoloModel= Dnn.readNetFromDarknet(cfgPath,weightsPath);`
```

did not work
I also tried using input stream from assets folder and then saving file

```
AssetManager assetManager= getAssets();
InputStream cfgStream= assetManager.open("yolov3_custom.cfg");
byte[] buffer= new byte[cfgStream.available()];
cfgStream.read(buffer);
File cfgFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "yolov3_customCp.cfg");
OutputStream outCfgStream= new FileOutputStream(cfgFile);
outCfgStream.write(buffer);
String cfgPath= cfgFile.getAbsolutePath();
Log.d("path: ", cfgPath);

InputStream weightsStream= assetManager.open("yolov3_custom_final.weights");
byte[] _buffer= new byte[weightsStream.available()];
weightsStream.read(_buffer);
File weightsFile= new File(getFilesDir(), "yolo_customCp.weights");
OutputStream outWeightsStream=new FileOutputStream(weightsFile);
outWeightsStream.write(_buffer);
String weightsPath= weightsFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

still I am not able to read the files in  Dnn.ReadFromDarknet()

Is there any way to do this??

also, for using `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` where should I put my files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the permission?
You can add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.something">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
        <application
        .....
```

Then add the permission request in the MainActivity onStart()

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    
        // Check External Storage Permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    
            // Request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
     

   }
}
```